# Textbox problem with onclick @

Tags: php, javascript

I'm just trying to display a table in client side from database as a distinct value from every column. Here i have fetched the value by using "select distinct ...." code and put this value in a single textbox

here is the code...

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>


<script type="text/javascript">
function onClick()
 {
   alert(document.form.thirdparty.value);

  }
</script>




</head>

<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form name="form" method="get" >

 <?php 
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('database',$con);
$res = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM tablename") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
$val=$row['count'];

} ?> 


 <input name="fino" type="text" id="fino" size="5" value="<?php echo $val." docs" ?>" style="border-style:hidden; color:#0083fa;" />


<table width="1474" height="270" border="0" >
  <tr>
    <td width="180" height="41">




          <input name="Item" type="DocumentType" id="textfield5" value="        Item"size="30" />    </td>
    <td width="180" height="41">


         <label>
    <td width="180" height="41">    <input type="text" name="textfield8" id="textfield8" style="visibility:hidden" /></td>
        </label>


      <label>
       <td width="180" height="41"> <input type="text" name="textfield9" id="textfield9" style="visibility:hidden"/></td>
        </label>





    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>

<?php
$a=mysql_query("select distinct language from tablename");
$c=0;
$i=1;
$x=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($a))
{
$b=$row['language'];
$i=$b;
$d=mysql_query("select count(*) as count from tablename where language='$i' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($d)) {
$e=$row['count'];
$cal=round(($e/$val)*100);


}
?>


 //in this textbox am using onclick function

      <input type="text"  size="30" style="height:<?php echo $cal.px?>"value="<?php echo "$i"."&nbsp;"."&nbsp;"."&nbsp;"."$e"." docs" ?>"name="language" id="textfield"onClick="onClick();" />

      <?php 
$i++;
$c++;
}
?> </td>
<td> 
<?php 
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('database',$con);
$a1=mysql_query("select distinct Subject from tablename");
$c1=0;
$i1=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($a1))
{
$b1=$row['Subject'];
$i1=$b1;
$d1=mysql_query("select count(*) as count from tablename where Subject='$i1' ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($d1)) {
$e1=$row['count'];
$cal1=round(($e1/$val)*100);
}
?>



        <input type="text" size="30" style="height:<?php echo $cal1.px?>" value="<?php echo "$i1"."&nbsp;"."&nbsp;"."&nbsp;"."$e1"." docs" ?>"name="item" id="textfield2" />
 <?php 
$i++;
$c++;
}
?>    </td>
    <td>


      <label>
       <td> <input type="text" name="textfield12" id="textfield12" style="visibility:hidden" /></td>
        </label>

      <label>
       <td> <input type="text" name="textfield13" id="textfield13" style="visibility:hidden" /></td>
        </label>

      <label>
       <td> <input type="text" name="textfield14" id="textfield14" style="visibility:hidden" /></td>
        </label>


      <label>
       <td> <input type="text" name="textfield15" id="textfield15" style="visibility:hidden" /> </td>
        </label>
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

  <blockquote>
   <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
 </blockquote>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want us to fix your code, you have to give us your code. Paste your JavaScript here.

Comment: this is a JavaScript problem. You are trying to access an object that does not exist. Can you post some code so folks can help you better?

Comment: @Dhi By posting code we mean *relevant* code.. throwing the whole code at us without proper explanation is not useful. Anyway, can't see anything related to onclick in your question - please explain what exactly is wrong and/or what you need.

Comment: @shadow.. thx shadow.. Actually what i want is i need do display distinct value into multiple textboxes.. thats y i used while loop.. then if i click on the distincted textbox it need to do another function depend on textbox value... r u clear now ... can u help?

Comment: @Dhi I think I got it, see my answer. By the way when using `@` you can't have `.` right after it as it would look for member called `shadow..` and such member does not exist. You can have space or dash though.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

The following is a sample where the value of the textbox is displayed in an alert box.
As the others have said, cannot suggest anything other than this without seeing code.

Example

```
<input type = 'text' id = 'myTextBox' onclick='alert(this.value)' />
```

Comment: The OP has not mentioned jQuery.

Comment: thanks everyone..... here i just attach the query please find what the mistake.... thanks once again....

Comment: thx dan and deep.... i have attach code in my question itself please find and give solution.... thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

First don't call your function `onclick` better name is something like `LanguageClick`.

Second, don't give same `id` to all elements.. if you don't have real use for it just omit the ID it won't break anything.

Third, proper event is `onfocus` as user can reach the textbox by pressing Tab key, which won't trigger the click event.

Code would look like this:

```
<input type="text" size="30" style="height:<?php echo $cal.px?>;" value="<?php echo "$i"."&nbsp;"."&nbsp;"."&nbsp;"."$e"." docs" ?>" name="language" onfocus="LanguageClick(this);" />
```

And the JavaScript code:

```
function LanguageClick(oTextbox) {
  var sValue = oTextbox.value;
  alert("You wrote: " + sValue);
}
```

As you pass `this` to the function, you have reference to the textbox element and you can read its `value` property.